# Should I extend the Binder class or use a Messenger?

Tags: android, service

In my app I've designed it to have a Service that gets data constantly (for good reason, it's from some sensors) and provides it to two clients:

- A UI Activity to display the live data
- Another service that logs the data

At any time, both, one or neither of these clients may be running.

I think that this service should be a Bound service, whereas the logging service is a Started service.

The Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Creating) for this says I should extend the Binder class, or use a Messenger if I want to access the service from another process.

This service, the logging service and the UI Activity will all be in the same apk, so they'll presumably be in the same process - but what is going to be the best solution here? I suspect the documentation might not be taking into account the possibility that I could have two clients in the same process as the service.

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

imrankhan's preferred solution (Binder) did seem to work, but in the end I opted for a Messenger as in practise I found this solution more flexible and logical to code.

Answer (score 10):

The Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Creating) clearly says 
**Extending the Binder class**

*If your service is private to your own application and runs in the same process as the client (which is common)*, you should create your interface by extending the Binder class and returning an instance of it from onBind(). The client receives the Binder and can use it to directly access public methods available in either the Binder implementation or even the Service.
This is the preferred technique when your service is merely a background worker for your own application. The only reason you would not create your interface this way is because your service is used by other applications or across separate processes.
**Using a Messenger**

*If you need your interface to work across different processes*, you can create an interface for the service with a Messenger. In this manner, the service defines a Handler that responds to different types of Message objects. This Handler is the basis for a Messenger that can then share an IBinder with the client, allowing the client to send commands to the service using Message objects. Additionally, the client can define a Messenger of its own so the service can send messages back.
This is the simplest way to perform interprocess communication (IPC), because the Messenger queues all requests into a single thread so that you don't have to design your service to be thread-safe.

So, the best option is to use a service by extending `IBinder` class when this service is a **local service**. When both services are created by using `Messenger` and `AIDL`, they are **remote services**.

Comment: Is that going to work with both the Service and Activity as clients concurrently?

Comment: yes it work for both and system delivers  same `IBinder` to all clients